# I can't add a view for HomeController Action index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

When i add a view for { public ActionResult Index()} with template:list,it will be error.
the error message is unable to load source https:\packagesource

I try to update (Package source) and (Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages) in nuget Manager , but it's useless.

my HomeController code:

```
namespace Outfit_Web.Controllers
{
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    user_dbEntities db = new user_dbEntities();
      
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var user = db.user_list.OrderBy(m => m.user_Id).ToList();
        return View(user);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";   
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()       
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        return View();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to add your view?

Comment: @mxmissile when i add view it will be error, message is unable to load source https:\packagesource, and i fix it by setting NuGet source today. very thank you for replying me!

Answer (score 0):

This's my questions,and I fix error myself today，The reason for the error is i don't add Nuget source in the Nuget package manager.

Resolution steps: tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Setting -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Sources -> add Name:NuGet feed v3
Source:https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

And Tick the box  Nuget feed v3,and cancel tick of Package source & Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages.Then add view will be success.
thank everyone who answer!